# Convert HTML in JSON file with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ngsanitize

Now I know to use `ngSanitize` and `ng-bind-html`, but can I use it with `ng-repeat` where I have the following logic:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k, v) in specs.webdev">
    <h3>{{::v["job-title"]}}</h3>
    <p>{{::v["job-body"]}}</p>
    United Kingdom Apply Here:
    <p>{{::v["job-apply"]}}</p>
</div>
```

`specs` (where I have multiple html tags) is retrieved from `JSON` file with `$http.get` and parsed with `.then`. So, values in `"job-title"`, "`job-body"`, `"job-apply"` contain HTML tags that I'm trying to display here.

How can I use `ng-bind-html` here?

Comment: Do the job-title, job-body and job-apply properties contain HTML tags which you want to maintain to display as correct HTML? Just trying to understand the question more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well, just doing

```
<div ng-repeat="(k, v) in specs.webdev">
  <h3 ng-bind-html="::v['job-title']"></h3>
  <p ng-bind-html="::v['job-body']"></p>
  United Kingdom Apply Here:
  <p ng-bind-html="::v['job-title']"></p>
</div>
```

That will render the content of v['job-title'] and other properties as HTML

Comment: Thanks, wow.. I've learned something new. Never thought to put it inside the html tag like this. :)